# How can I pass parameterized tests to filter in dotnet test

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core

How I can pass parameterized tests into filter for dotnet test command?

I tried something like:

```
dotnet test --filter 'FullyQualifiedName=QAutomation.Tests.NUnit.Fixture.Test2("first",3,4)'
```

and

```
dotnet test --filter 'FullyQualifiedName=QAutomation.Tests.NUnit.Fixture.Test2\\("sdas",3,4\\)'
```

but it doesn't work.

I have parameterized tests:

```cs
 [Test]
 [TestCase("first", 3, 4)]
 [TestCase("second", 1, 5)]
 public void Test(string s, int a, int b)
 {
     Assert.Fail("Fail");
 }
```

Comment: have you come up with some solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it to work

```
dotnet test --filter 'FullyQualifiedName=QAutomation.Tests.NUnit.Fixture.Test2\(\"sdas\",3,4\)'
```

did the trick in my case (dotnet core nunit test project).

Comment: Sadly if any parameter value contains any `=` character, then I haven't figured out yet any way to mask that character